# firebase only allow certain properties to be set

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How do you set a rule for allowed properties? I only want the created and last updated properties to be able to be set for the user. I tried using a variable to catch unspecified values but this gives a permission_denied error. I'm assuming because it is parsing either created or lastUpdated as its value.

```
"u": {
            ".read": true,
            "$uid": {
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
                ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['created','lastUpdated'])",
                "$other": {
                    ".validate": false
                },
                "created": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
                },
                "lastUpdated": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
                }
            },
        },
```

The write action that failed:

```
var userObj = { 
    uid: user['uid'], 
    created: new Date().getTime(), 
    lastUpdated: new Date().getTime() 
} 
database.ref('u/' + user['uid']).set(userObj);
```

Comment: Can you show a write action that fails with these rules but that you want to succeed?

Comment: var userObj = {
  uid: user['uid'],
  created: new Date().getTime(),
  lastUpdated: new Date().getTime()
 }
 database.ref('u/' + user['uid']).set(userObj);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding three properties to the node: `uid`, `created` and `lastUpdated`. Your security rules only allow `created` and `lastUpdated`.

Given that the `uid` is already used as the key, the write should probably be:

```
var userObj = { 
    created: new Date().getTime(), 
    lastUpdated: new Date().getTime() 
} 
database.ref('u/' + user['uid']).set(userObj);
```

I'd also consider user [ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps) for the times, which ensures the server determines the timestamp and that both values will be the same.

Comment: Above and beyond! Thanks for your help and the reference to servers timestamp!